# show an element after clicking two or more different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different elements and want to connect them with lines after clicking on them. The problem is that each element can be connected with several other elements, so there are more than one possibilities to combine each element, which means I have to click all of the elements I want to be connected to show the lines between.

For example: when you click `#button1` and `#button2` a line appears between them. When you click now `#button3` a line between `#button2` and `#button3` would show up in addition to the first line. (The lines are images which should be shown after clicking the buttons).

I couldn't find any solutions where you can trigger an event after clicking two or more elements. Hope somebody can help me!

```css
#button1 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#button2 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
#button3 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
}
#button4 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
#line12 {
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 17.5px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line24 {
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line14 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line13 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line32 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="line12">
  <img src="img/line12.png">
</div>
<div id="line14">
  <img src="img/line14.png">
</div>
<div id="line24">
  <img src="img/line24.png">
</div>
<div id="line13">
  <img src="img/line13.png">
</div>
<div id="line32">
  <img src="img/line32.png">
</div>

<div id="button1">show lines 1</div>
<div id="button2">show lines 2</div>
<div id="button3">show lines 3</div>
<div id="button4">show lines 4</div>
```

Comment: Could you please include your JS code in the example.

Comment: Sorry, there is none. I haven´t find anything that runs with more than one trigger

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Remember that you should incluse your js

```js
var firstEl = -1;
$("#button1").on("click",function(){
  if (firstEl == -1){
    firstEl = 1;
    } else {
      $("line" + firstEl + "1").show();
      console.log("show " + "line" + firstEl + "1");
      firstEl = -1;
    }
});

$("#button2").on("click",function(){
  if (firstEl == -1){
    firstEl = 2;
    } else {
      $("line" + firstEl + "2").show();
      console.log("show " + "line" + firstEl + "2");
      firstEl = -1;
    }
});

$("#button3").on("click",function(){
  if (firstEl == -1){
    firstEl = 3;
    } else {
      $("line" + firstEl + "3").show();
      console.log("show " + "line" + firstEl + "3");
      firstEl = -1;
    }
});

$("#button4").on("click",function(){
  if (firstEl == -1){
    firstEl = 4;
    } else {
      $("line" + firstEl + "4").show();
      console.log("show " + "line" + firstEl + "4");
      firstEl = -1;
    }
});
```

```css
#button1{
 border:#000000 solid;
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 }
 
#button2{
 border:#000000 solid;
 width:100px;
 margin-left:300px;}
 
#button3{
 border:#000000 solid;
 width:100px;
 margin-top:175px;
 margin-left:0px;
 float:left;}
 
#button4{
 border:#000000 solid;
 width:100px;
 margin-top:175px;
 margin-left:300px;
 }


#line12 {
 margin-left:55px; 
 margin-top:17.5px; 
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}

#line24 {
 margin-left: 350px; 
 margin-top:33px; 
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}

#line14 {
 margin-left: 50px; 
 margin-top:33px; 
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}

#line13 {
 margin-left: 50px; 
 margin-top:33px; 
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}

#line32 {
 margin-left: 50px; 
 margin-top:33px; 
 position:absolute;
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line12"><img src="img/line12.png"></div>
<div id="line14"><img src="img/line14.png"></div>
<div id="line24"><img src="img/line24.png"></div>
<div id="line13"><img src="img/line13.png"></div>
<div id="line32"><img src="img/line32.png"></div>

<div id="button1">show lines 1</div>
<div id="button2">show lines 2</div>
<div id="button3">show lines 3</div>
<div id="button4">show lines 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code :

HTML :

```
<div id="line12" class="line-image-container">
  <img src="img/line12.png">
</div>
<div id="line14" class="line-image-container">
  <img src="img/line14.png">
</div>
<div id="line24" class="line-image-container">
  <img src="img/line24.png">
</div>
<div id="line13" class="line-image-container">
  <img src="img/line13.png">
</div>
<div id="line32" class="line-image-container">
  <img src="img/line32.png">
</div>

<div id="button1" data-line-no="1">show lines 1</div>
<div id="button2" data-line-no="2">show lines 2</div>
<div id="button3" data-line-no="3">show lines 3</div>
<div id="button4" data-line-no="4">show lines 4</div>
```

jQuery :

```
var i=0;
var line_obj = array();
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.line-image-container').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    if(i<=2) {
        var line = $(this).attr('data-line-no');
        line_obj.push(line);
        i++;
    }

    if(i == 2) {
        $('#line'+line_obj[0]+line_obj[1]).css('visibility', 'visible');
        i = 0;
    }

});
```

It would be better if you add your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var buttonClicks = [];
  $(".test").click(function(e) {
    var btnId = $(e.target).attr('id');
    // make sure the same button wasnt clicked twice
    if (buttonClicks[0] === btnId) 
      return;
    buttonClicks.push(btnId);
    if (buttonClicks.length === 2) { // 2 buttons clicked      
      // put your line drawing logic here
      console.log("Show line between " + buttonClicks[0] + " and " + buttonClicks[1]);
      buttonClicks = []; // reset button clicks
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button1 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#button2 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
#button3 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
}
#button4 {
  border: #000000 solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 175px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
#line12 {
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 17.5px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line24 {
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line14 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line13 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#line32 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line12">
  <img src="img/line12.png">
</div>
<div id="line14">
  <img src="img/line14.png">
</div>
<div id="line24">
  <img src="img/line24.png">
</div>
<div id="line13">
  <img src="img/line13.png">
</div>
<div id="line32">
  <img src="img/line32.png">
</div>

<div class="test" id="button1">show lines 1</div>
<div class="test" id="button2">show lines 2</div>
<div class="test" id="button3">show lines 3</div>
<div class="test" id="button4">show lines 4</div>
```